# Find the most popular vehicle for a hire

Tags: sql

I have this table and I need to find the most popular vehicle for a hire based on the serial number.

```
+------------+---------------+
| hire_id | serial_number |
+------------+---------------+
|         1 | 99UU123       |
|         2 | JBB45         |
|         1 | YQE221RR      |
|         3 | UTY1236Y      |
|         4 | YY32RR12      |
|         4 | TRW14         |
|         5 | TRW14         |
|         6 | JBB45         |
+------------+---------------+
```

the output should be

```
+------------+---------------+
| most popular| serial_number |
+------------+---------------+
|        2    | JBB45         |
|        2    | TRW14         |
...............................
```

How could I get this output using SQL command?

Comment: Which `Database` you are using

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. What have you done so far to try and obtain that output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Group by` and `having` clause

```
SELECT Count(serial_number) most_popular,
       serial_number
FROM   tablename
GROUP  BY serial_number
HAVING Count(serial_number) = (SELECT Count(serial_number) ss
                               FROM   from tablename
                               GROUP  BY serial_number
                               ORDER  BY ss DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.could you explain how does it work briefly

Comment: @muthana First query is just counts how many times each `serial_number` is present and in the second query am doing the same thing but it returns only the max count. So the first query is filtered with this count

Answer (score 0):

Below query will work

```
SELECT   COUNT(serial_number) AS `most_popular`, serial_number 
FROM     your_table_name
GROUP BY serial_number
ORDER BY most_popular DESC
LIMIT    2;
```

Comment: `LIMIT 2` only works in the _example_ case.  For his actual data, we have no idea how many of the "top" serials he has.